# SQL Inner Join and Grouping

Tags: sql, sql-server, inner-join

It's been a while since I've done SQL, but I have a rather pressing issue.

My db-layout is as following: [image]

Now, starting from a `Users.ID`, I want to get all the `Rounds` the user has played. The user could be `Hosts.HostID`, `Host.GuestID`, or even both. Where he is both, it should not show op in the results.

The results I need from the Query are the `Hosts.Name` and all the fields of `Rounds`. In general what I want to do is display a list of all the `Hosts` (actually these are the Games) in which the user has participated, as a Host or as a Guest, along with perhaps a total score. When clicking on this, some dropdown will appear showing the individual round scores, words, ...

Now I was wondering whether this was possible in a single query. Of course I could do a query getting all the `Hosts` and then per `Host` a query for each `Round`, but that doesn't seem that performant. This is what I've come up with so far:

```
SELECT  Rounds.ID, Rounds.GameID, Rounds.Round, Rounds.Score, Rounds.Word
        , Hosts.ID, Hosts.HostID, Hosts.GuestID 
FROM    Rounds INNER JOIN Hosts 
ON      Rounds.GameID = Hosts.ID 
INNER JOIN Users 
ON     Hosts.hostID = Users.ID 
WHERE  Users.ID = 5
```

The issue is however that it doesn't filter out where the user is both host AND guest, and I can't seem to Group it by `Hosts.ID` either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add  `Hosts.hostID <> Hosts.guestID` to the where clause.

Comment: And what would that achieve? Wouldn't that simply *exclude* users that are both a host and a guest?

Comment: No, that would exclude hosts where the user is both host and guest.

Comment: Yes, hosts, that's what I meant, sorry. The main point, however, that it would exclude those `Hosts` rows completely while the OP seems to want to select them, just not duplicate the results for both `HostID` and `GuestID` when those reference the same user.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using SQL Server 2005 or later version, you could modify your present query like this:

```
SELECT  Rounds.ID, Rounds.GameID, Rounds.Round, Rounds.Score, Rounds.Word
        , Hosts.ID, Hosts.HostID, Hosts.GuestID 
FROM    Rounds INNER JOIN Hosts 
ON      Rounds.GameID = Hosts.ID 
CROSS APPLY
        (
        SELECT Hosts.HostID
        UNION
        SELECT Hosts.GuestID
        ) AS u (UserID)
WHERE   u.UserID = 5
;
```

The CROSS APPLY clause would produce either one or two rows, depending on whether `HostID` and `GuestID` are equal. In either event, the WHERE condition would ultimately leave at most one. Thus, the above query would give you only the games (with all their rounds) where the specified user participated.

And from that query you could easily get to something like this:

```
SELECT  Hosts.ID,
        TotalScore = SUM(Rounds.Score)
FROM
        ...
GROUP BY
        Hosts.ID
;
```